# Definition query not updating

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.3, definition-query, sdelayer

I have an ArcMap 10.3 MXD in which which I am trying to update the definition query of an enterprise geodatabase layer using Python:

```
import arcpy, os, re
from arcpy import env

inmxd = r'C:\Temp\Tenure_Shire Notification.mxd'
tenID = 'E40/01300'
env.workspace = os.path.dirname(inmxd)
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(inmxd)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Main Map")[0]
tenLMAT = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Tenement Application - Live Mining Act Tenure")[0]
oldExp = tenLMAT.definitionQuery
oldTenID = re.split(r"\'", oldExp)[1]
newExp = oldExp.replace(oldTenID,tenID)
tenLMAT.definitionQuery = newExp
```

My issue is that using this code, my definition query has not changed when I check the layer properties. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have also tried arcpy.RefreshActiveView() after setting the definition query

Comment: Please edit your question to state whether you are running this code from within arcmap or from a standalone script, whether you are saving the mxd in your script then opening it in a new arcmap session.

Comment: On the line oldTenID = re.split(r"\'", oldExp)[1] you're escaping a raw string, it should be oldTenID = re.split("\'", oldExp)[1] (without the r) or oldTenID = re.split(r"'", oldExp)[1] (without the escape char). As it stands you're looking for \' to split and that isn't likely in your definition query.

Comment: I have run the script both from within arcmap and from a standalone script. I have also tried saving it.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your help. I have taken out the r in the split expression without any change in the query result

Comment: Can you reveal what the query is and what you're expecting to get in newExp please. If you're running this from command line or on a mapdocument other than the one that is currently open have you called mxd.save(); when running in ArcMap have you changed the mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(inmxd) to mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')?

Comment: Hi Michael, the old query would be something like TENEMENT_ID = 'E47/01300' and the new query would be TENEMENT_ID = 'E40/01300'. I ran the script from a script tool in an empty map document with mxd.save() after setting the query and nothing changed.

Comment: Have to note that both tenements are valid

Comment: Have got it to work with the mxd.save() from an empty map document. Figured out that I had not changed the hard coded variable! Thanks FelixIP and Michael for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer is very simple. Run the script outside the active map document and use mxd.save() after setting the definition query:

```
import arcpy, os, re
from arcpy import env

inmxd = r'C:\Temp\Tenure_Shire Notification.mxd'
tenID = 'E40/01300'
env.workspace = os.path.dirname(inmxd)
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(inmxd)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Main Map")[0]
tenLMAT = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Tenement Application - Live Mining Act Tenure")[0]
oldExp = tenLMAT.definitionQuery
oldTenID = re.split("\'", oldExp)[1]
newExp = oldExp.replace(oldTenID,tenID)
tenLMAT.definitionQuery = newExp

mxd.save()
```

Thanks for everyone's suggestions.